# Elementor Sever error 500 and server error 503 leads to published content being invinsible

Tags: wordpress, admin, elementor, internal-server-error

Website got hit by Japanese spam hack thus did many changes to .htaccess, index.php such as changing file permissions etc prior to this elementor was working all good. Running on php 7.4 on direct admin wordpress based.

To get rid of the hack used several new plugins and cleaning up of code.

Currently the error comes when try to update content it says Server 500 error and sometimes Server 503 error. In the event content goes through with update then the page when viewed only loads the header and footer and no body/content that elementor should have generated.

Things that was tried to fix;
Tried increase php mem limit, tried make new page add content and publish, tried deactivate some plugins and see if solves, tried upgrading plugin to newer versions, tried elementor different editor loader enable, tried elementor regenerate under tools and sync library also, tried elementor safe mode, tried change php version to all possible combinations.

Here is debug info displayed on page that gets updated but content empty.
[image]

Any ideas how to solve?

Here is further log of code;
2022-11-19 22:18:56.193669 [NOTICE] [1540710] [T0] [2402:4000:2081:28a9:d53c:d245:3ca9:96a3:61778-H3:93B0CE471FDC440A-4#APVH_www.domain.com:443] [STDERR] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/dom/domains/domain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/embed.php on line 156
2022-11-19 22:18:56.193720 [NOTICE] [1540710] [T0] [2402:4000:2081:28a9:d53c:d245:3ca9:96a3:61778-H3:93B0CE471FDC440A-4#APVH_www.domain.com:443] [STDERR] PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /home/ dom/domains/domain.com/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3366
2022-11-19 22:18:56.193733 [NOTICE] [1540710] [T0] [2402:4000:2081:28a9:d53c:d245:3ca9:96a3:61778-H3:93B0CE471FDC440A-4#APVH_www.domain.com:443] [STDERR] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home/ dom/domains/domain.com/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3373

Comment: If it's hacked, you need to restore the last known unhacked web backup, because if you kept using the same basecode, the new backdoor that's installed will be there and... it can be used once more to do more attack.. 2nd is after restoring the page, please.. update the plugins and probe what's wrong with the code...

Comment: Got rid of all the malicious code just unsure why elementor ain't working with above errors

Comment: have you restore to last known working code? And also restore the DB? elementor is a Builder, so you need to check also the DB data...

Comment: The error was able to be resolved by downgrading elementor to version 2.9.14 so it seems upgraded version probably conflicting with plugins and themes but that also unlikely since in safe mode it should work but it didn't. Either way doing above will solve it.

Comment: I think it's better to look into the changelog, because if you downgrade, there are several security vulnerability... yeah... so in short, you are not protected by anything...